# Fire other checkboxes onclick() when main checkbox is selected/unselected

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have read many other question on SO regarding selecting all checkboxes, but couldn't find one that says how to trigger other checkboxes actions.

I have a main checkbox, when this checkbox is selected all other checkboxes are selected as well. 
The thing is, other checkboxes have to perform their own action e.g disable text fields .etc if they are checked/unchecked. I achieved this by adding onclick to each checkbox. So how to call each checkbox onclick (or make each checkbox to perform their action) if the main checkbox is selected?

After reading about this I have made the following:

```
      // main checkbox functin that checks/unchecks other checkboxes. 

  function toggleAllCheckBoxes(source , operationType) {
                checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("checkBox" + operationType);
                for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
                checkbox.checked = source.checked;
               // checkbox.addEventListener('click', true); // this is wrong.
            }


  //this will toggle text fields enabled/disabled
 function toggleDisable(oldTable, newTable , checkBox)
    {
        if( document.getElementById(newTable) !=null)// in case to toggle only old table
        {
            document.getElementById(newTable).disabled = checkBox.checked;
        }

        document.getElementById(oldTable).disabled = checkBox.checked;
    }
```

main checkbox:

```
All<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleAllCheckBoxes(this , '<?=$operationType?>')"/>
```

Other checkboxes

```
  X<input name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="toggleDisable('<?= $originalTableId?>' , '<?= $backupTableId?>' , this )" type="checkbox" />
```

So far this works fine, except, text fields are not being enabled/disabled if main checkbox is selected. Although single checkboxes are able to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. There is no `for each` operator in JavaScript. You'll need to use a
   normal for loop here.
2. You don't want to set the `checked` attribute
   for the checkbox because, as you've seen, that will bypass all event
   handlers. Instead, call `click()` on the checkbox and it will be
   checked (or unchecked) and all event handlers will be called.

That will end up looking like this in `toggleAllCheckBoxes`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
    checkboxes[i].click();
```

Here's a Fiddle to try this code out on: http://jsfiddle.net/z4Ltc/

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine, had no idea bout .click(). 
Anyways, your code is toggling my other check boxes so i added an if to check if the box status is diff than main box. 
If you would allow me, I added some code to your answer to make it suitable as an answer for this question.

Comment: btw,, my for each loop is working, not sure how but the work is done here :D

Comment: If it fits what you need, I don't see a problem. Thanks for accepting. You're edit was rejected (not by me) so you might want to add it as a comment.

Comment: The main checkbox will basically only toggle other checkboxes, not make them the same. So by this, all would become either checked or unchecked. 

  if(checkboxes[i].checked != source.checked)
            {
                checkboxes[i].click();
            }